# Import CSV into Elasticsearch with Logstash

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I use the ELK stack to parse CSV files and send them to ElasticSearch after parsing them with logstash.

Unfortunately, I have a problem:

When I send my files to the listening directory of the "input" of my logstash pipeline, the records are doubled, see triplets, without my asking anything ...

Indeed :

This is what my pipeline looks like:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/XXX/report/*.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ";"
     columns => ["Name", "Status", "Category", "Type", "EndPoint", "Group", "Policy", "Scanned At", "Reported At", "Affected Application"]
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "malwarebytes-report"
  }
stdout {}
}
```

When I send my first file containing 28 records in "/home/XXX/report/", this is what ElasticSearch says:

```
[root @ lrtstfpe1 confd]#curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'
health status index uuid pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open malwarebytes-report PO4g6rKRTb6yuMDb7i-6sg 5 1 28 0 25.3kb 25.3kb
```

So far so good, but when I send my second file of 150 records ...:

```
[root @ lrtstfpe1 confd]#curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'
health status index uuid pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open malwarebytes-report PO4g6rKRTb6yuMDb7i-6sg 5 1 328 0 263.3kb 263.3kb
```

The 150 recordings have been doubled and added to the first 28 ...

What's going on ??

Several days that I am stuck on the problem, I really need you ..

UPDATE :

```
You need to look in /etc/logstash/conf.d and see if there are any other config files there
```

The problem is that I only have one pipeline in this folder ... So:

I just completely uninstalled the ELK stack (`rpm -e elasticsearch kibana logstash filebeat`) as well as any ELK traces (`rm -rf /var/lib/ELK/ var/log/ELK/ etc/default/ELK /usr/share/ELK` ...) So, nothing anywhere.

I just reinstall everything:

```
rpm -ivh elasticsearch-6.2.3.rpm
rpm -ivh kibana-6.2.3-x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh logstash-6.2.3.rpm
```

And start the services: `service ELK restart`

Then, in terms of configurations:
`/etc/elasticsearch.yml` is completely by default.
`/etc/kibana.ym`l is completely by default.
`/etc/logstash.yml` is completely by default.

Then, I put my one and ONLY pipeline named "pip.conf" in `/etc/logstash/conf.d/`
Its configuration:

```
input {
   file {
     path => "/home/report/*.csv"
     start_position => "beginning"
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
     separator => ";"
     columns => ["Name","Status","Category","Type","EndPoint","Group","Policy","Scanned At","Reported At","Affected Application"]
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "malwarebytes-report"
  }
stdout{}
}
```

And finally, I launch my pipeline :
I go into `/usr/share/logstash` and I execute :

```
bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/pip.conf
```

After few secondes, my pipeline is listening, and now, I put my `file1.csv` and my `file2.csv` into `/home/report/`.

`file1.csv` contains 28 records and `file2.csv` contains 150 records.

But now, when I check my index : `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'`
My index "malwarebytes-report" contains 357 records ... (150x2 + 28x2 ...)

I don't understand NOTHING ....

Comment: The problem is probably that your `sincedb_path` is set to null so Logstash might re-read all files everytime. Can you try to set `sincedb_path` to something meaningful so it can remember what it has read already? Are you running Logstash several times?

Comment: Hello ! 

I deleted the line about sincedb_path to replace by its default value, and it's the same behaviour...

I don't run logstash several times. I launch my pipeline, and I let it listen to /home/XXX/*.csv, and during this time I send my files into this path

..

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple logstash processes that are running at the same time (one that didn't stop/kill properly)? Can you verify first?

Comment: I can't have multiple logstash process at the same time, but yes I'm sure, only one is running, see this picture : 
https://ibb.co/mmBx6c

Comment: So now, when I send a simple file with 150 records, one index is created, but with 272 records... absolutly insane...

Comment: Do you have nested fields in your documents?

Comment: What do mean by "nested fields" the first lines (my columns and first records) of my csv looks like :
https://ibb.co/eGZunH

Comment: PS : I just tried without logstash, just with FileBeat which listening my directory and send them to elasticsearch, it works fine, it send my real numbers of records...

filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/log/*.csv
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: true
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3
setup.kibana:
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

But I need to pass through logstash to parse my files

Answer (score 0):

If you able to use other tools other than logstash in order to load files into elasticsearch you can you elasticsearch-loader.

I'm the author of [moshe/elasticsearch_loader](https://github.com/moshe/elasticsearch_loader)
I wrote ESL for this exact problem.
You can download it with pip:

```
pip install elasticsearch-loader
```

And then you will be able to load csv files into elasticsearch by issuing:

```
elasticsearch_loader --index incidents --type incident csv file1.csv
```

Comment: How do you pass it the configuration? I mean the host where it is installed: http://10.6.0.81:7919/elasticsearch/

Comment: `--es-host http://10.6.0.81:7919` take a look at the docs - https://github.com/moshe/elasticsearch_loader